# Converting markdown to HTML with JavaScript - restricting sppported syntax

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, markdown

I am using **marked.js** currently to convert *markdown* to HTML, so the users of my Web-App can create a structured content. I am wondering if there is a way to restrict the supported syntax tu just an sub-set, like

#### headers

*italic text*

**bold text**

- lists with only 1 depth of indentation

> quotes

I would like to prohibit conversion of list with multiple levels of indentation, code blocks, headers in lists ...

The reason is, that my WebApp should the users to create content in a specific way and if there will be possibility create some crazy structured content (list of headers, code in headers, lists of images ...) someone will for sure do it.

Comment: It might be easier to parse it to HTML then use some DOM queries to see if there are unwanted elements or structures using selectors, e.g. `doc.querySelector('li ul')` will find a nested ul, `'li ol'` a nested ol, etc.

Comment: Circa 10 years ago I had a similar issue, at the time it was easier to implement our own very simple parser to only support the 3-4 tags we needed rather than try to restrict a library package.  There may be better ways now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few difference options:

Marked.js uses a multi-step method to parse Markdown. It uses a lexer, which breaks the document up into tokens, a parser to convert those tokens to a abstract syntax tree (AST) and a renderer to convert the AST to HTML. You can [override](https://marked.js.org/#/USING_PRO.md) any of those pieces to alter the handling of various parts of the syntax.

For example, if you simply wanted to ignore lists and leave them out of the rendered HTML, replace the `list` function from the renderer with one which returns an empty string.

Or, if you want the parser to act as if lists are not even a supported feature of Markdown, you could remove the `list` and `listitem` methods from the parser. In that case, the list would remain in the output, but would be treated as a paragraph instead.

Or, if you want to support one level of lists, but not nested lists, then you could replace the `list` and/or `listitem` methods in the parser with your own implementation that parses lists as you desire.

Note that there are also a number [advanced options](https://marked.js.org/#/USING_ADVANCED.md), which use the above methods to alter the parser and/or render in various ways. For the most part, those options would not provide the features you are asking for, but browsing though the [source code](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/blob/master/lib/marked.js) might give you some ideas of how to implement your own modifications.

However, there is the `sanitize` option, which will accept a `sanitizer` function. You could provide your own sanitizer which removed any unwanted elements from the HTML output. This would result in a similar end result to overriding the renderer, but would be implemented differently. Depending on what you want to accomplish, one or the other may be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use [Commonmark.js](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js), parse the input ant than walk the parsed tree and remove all nodes with/without specific type. See [this example](https://repl.it/repls/ElderlyFrequentOperatingenvironment), it worked fine for images, but failed for code blocks.

Downside of this approach is, that the parsed markdown source will be traversed two-times: one time for editing and second time for rendering.